# Usual Wireless Password Rejected

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I own an:

Linksys WMP600N PCI Wireless Adapter with Dual-Band

and have recently installed Ubuntu.  It detects my home network (with about 3 bars), however, when I enter the wireless password (which I know to be correct from my Windows 7 install) it simply attempts to connect and then asks for the password again.

Hopefully this is a sign of something else that needs fixing, but what I do not know.

Does this sound like a card specific problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you use WEP security, try changing it to WPA. That worked for me with a Marvell Topdog adapter using ndiswrapper.

Comment: Other wireless settings should be checked as well. I have a 2WIRE wireless gateway provided by our ISP, which uses a shared key (instead of Ubuntu's default of open). If any of the settings don't match, it seems Ubuntu's default response is to say your password is wrong...make sure everything else matches your wireless settings as close as possible and try again.

Comment: I meant change the router's security from a WEP password to a WPA password, unless Skolem doesn't know what these are to begin with. In this case, Warriorlng64 is correct. Check all of the settings on the router for consistency with Ubuntu.